# How to approximate a smooth function

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, approximation, matlab, inverse-problems

Now I have a target smooth function f which is infinitely differentiable over $R^d$, $f \in C^{\inf}(R^d)$. $f = \Sigma c_ig_i(x)$, where $c_i$s are unknown coefficients and $g_i(x)$ is a smooth function defined on the distance from $x$ to some point $x_i \in R^d$. For instance, $g_1(x)=exp(-(x-x_1)^2)$ in 1D and $g_1(x)=exp(-||x-x_1||_2^2)$ in 2D. I am supposed to approximate $f$ as more accurately as possible. Furthermore, I only care about some prescribed point like $x_1$, so as long as the approximation is best around $x_1$ locally, the result is optimal. This means I only need to obtain a function $f_{appr}$ such that $||f_{appr}-f||$ is small around $x_1$.

I have been trying to use Lagrange interpolation with least square solution, which employs polynomails.

Is it possible to make use of Fourier analysis or regression method? I am not good at sine and cosine function theory, nor inverse problem area. So any comments?

Attached are two cases which show the exact function $f$ values in 1D.

[image]

Comment: [Lanczos Resampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling)

Comment: @FelixMarin That is inspiring. Thanks! I just added two pictures to illustrate my function. The function is always localized. The max is over 1, is that okay? BTW, is there any Matlab function for Lanczos Resampling?

Comment: I don't use MatLab. Sorry.

Comment: Do you have any hint on what the function might look like? It sure seems to be something along the line $e^{-\alpha (x - \beta)^2} \sin (\gamma x + \delta)$...

Comment: @vonbrand Thank you! The function is a linear combination of basis functions like $e^{−α(x−β)2}$ and that's why it looks like what you said. You are smart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution for that is to use [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation). Perhaps the nicest solution to the equations is the one given by Wilf in his [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Thanks @vonbrand I downloaded the book and which part I'm supposed to look at? With spline interpolation, should I obtain first and second derivative values for each node except the end points?

Comment: Do you know how I can reply to somebody with @? I don't seem to use it correctly.

Comment: @user2820584 Just put the "at" symbol in front of their name.

Comment: @user2820584 If you are using Matlab, you don't have to worry about calculating any of that. Just specify the `'spline'` option to the `interp1()` function.

Comment: @vonbrand Thank you so very much for your time!!! You have a great day!

Comment: Search for "spline," the discussion is in section 1.4 (but you'll need much of what comes before to understand what is going on). You don't need to compute any derivatives, what the interpolation does is to fit cubic polynomials that pass through the points and such that at the "seams" the derivatives agree so the curve is smooth.